# Problem in extracting text from Xpath using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am using Selenium to extract data from the following page.

Page url: www2.miami-dadeclerk.com/cef/CitationSearch.aspx

Click on Folio: 0131230371470 .
Click on the first one.

I have used the following code to extract certain information:

```
templist = []

status = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="lblCitationHeader"]').text
total_due = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="lblCitationHeader"]').text
issue_dept = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="form1"]/div[4]/div[9]/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]').text
lien_placed = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="lblLienPlaced"]').text

Table_dict = {
    'Status': status,
    'Total Due': total_due,
    'Issuing Department': issue_dept,
    'Lien_Placed': lien_placed
    }

templist.append(Table_dict)
df = pd.DataFrame(templist)
```

The result coming is as follows:

```
    Status  Total Due   Issuing Department  Lien_Placed
0   Citation No.: 2010 - S001916 Issue Date: 1/ ... Citation No.: 2010 - S001916 Issue Date: 1/ ... 05 ANIMAL SERVICES DEPARTMENT (305) 629-7387
```

Here all the data that is under lblCitationHeader is coming under Status and Total due.

For that I had extracted their Xpaths:

```
Status: //*[@id="lblCitationHeader"]/text()[3]
Total Due: //*[@id="lblCitationHeader"]/text()[4]
```

When I am entering the above in the code:

```
status = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="lblCitationHeader"]/text()[3]').text
```

The following error is coming:

```
Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression .//*[@id="lblCitationHeader"]/text()[3]"] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string './/*[@id="lblCitationHeader"]/text()[3]"]' is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: chrome=96.0.4664.110)
```

I understand Xpath is used to locate the element and not text. However I am not being able to locate the section in which the text is stored and return it.

Image for reference:
[image]

The data's I want to extract are:-

STATUS
TOTAL DUE
ISSUING DEPT
LIEN PLACED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the current document *STATUS* *TOTAL DUE* and *ISSUING DEPT* fields have a value and to extract the values you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded/50474905#50474905) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

Code Block:

```
driver.get("https://www2.miami-dadeclerk.com/cef/CitationSearch.aspx")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Folio"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#txtFolioNumber"))).send_keys("0131230371470")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#btnFolioSearch"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table tbody>tr>td>a>span"))).click()
status = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[5].textContent;', WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span#lblCitationHeader")))).strip()
total_due = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span#lblCitationHeader")))).strip()
issue_dept = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//strong[contains(., 'Issuing Department:')]//following::td[1]/span"))).text
print(f"{status}--{total_due}--{issue_dept}")
```

Console Output:

```
* DEPARTMENT CLOSED *--$0.00--05 ANIMAL SERVICES DEPARTMENT (305) 629-7387
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```